# How do I POST data from a Java REST service with angular.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, angularjs

I'm using the default JEE7 REST application on Netbeans. 
I follow this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kFm45u1koOI

I finished this tutorial and then I tried to keep develop for my practice, first I change my databases with MySQL and work nicely.

But I can't figure out how I can POST or PUT new data on my databases.
I tried to create a full CRUD apps but I can't find a good tutorial or simple for me.

Can someone help or guide on this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the docs for the Angular `$resource` object: [ngResource documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

The example you were working with uses a $resource for a `GET`. Changing that to a `POST` just requires changing the `method` parameter.

There are lots of good references for using ngResource, not the least of which the official documentation. But this tutorial looks like it hits the basics and might give you some structure for getting started:

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/

Answer (score 0):

You can use $http.post or $http.put from angularjs app. See the link below.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http